# Sidekiq can't see my UserMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def send_async_email
        UserMailer.registration(self).deliver
    end

    def send_sync_email
        UserMailer.delay.registration(self)
    end
end
```

rails console:

```
u = User.last
u.send_sync_email #=> Rendered user_mailer/registration.text.erb (0.4ms)
u.send_async_email #=> "5da2ec14f77b8191bebb2be6"
```

sidekiq output:

```
2014-04-25T19:08:41Z 40831 TID-owap5t5sw WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'UserMailer'\n- :registration\n- - !ruby/object:User\n    attributes:\n      id: 35\n      user_name: Smot2hu2222\n      email: starker@gmail.com\n      password_digest: $2a$10$Ke2BEuuVZVwNOzSP2slxcOU7RliPSzpIaU.DmkqrvGwcJnR0kkwie\n      created_at: 2014-04-25 18:45:29.982656000 Z\n      updated_at: 2014-04-25 18:45:30.065059000 Z\n      register_key: 9af86f5ef9131ae515c71b728149f9aed1455aaa\n state: unregistered\n"], "jid"=>"5da2ec14f77b8191bebb2be6", "enqueued_at"=>1398452587.3401864, "error_message"=>"undefined class/module UserMailer", "error_class"=>"ArgumentError", "failed_at"=>1398452587.3426342, "retry_count"=>4, "retried_at"=>1398452921.5191402}
2014-04-25T19:08:41Z 40831 TID-owap5t5sw WARN: undefined class/module UserMailer
2014-04-25T19:08:41Z 40831 TID-owap5t5sw WARN: /home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:334:in `path2class'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:334:in `resolve_class'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:71:in `deserialize'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:104:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Scalar'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:259:in `block in register_empty'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:259:in `each'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:259:in `register_empty'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:122:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Sequence'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:240:in `visit_Psych_Nodes_Document'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:15:in `visit'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:20:in `accept'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:35:in `to_ruby'
/home/starkers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:130:in `load'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/extensions/action_mailer.rb:16:in `perform'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122:in `call'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:122:in `block in invoke'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:62:in `call'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:22:in `with_context'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:124:in `block in invoke'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `call'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `invoke'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:49:in `block in process'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:92:in `stats'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/sidekiq-3.0.0/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:48:in `process'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `public_send'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `dispatch'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322:in `block in handle_message'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416:in `block in task'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
/home/starkers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13:in `block in create'
```

I'm guessing this is something stupid? I need to configure sidekiq to load my mailers, something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to restart sidekiq. Blush. Do this by pressing `crtl` + `c` and then starting it again with `bundle exec sidekiq`:

sidekiq:

```
    ^[^C2014-04-25T19:16:11Z 40831 TID-9048o INFO: Shutting down
2014-04-25T19:16:12Z 40831 TID-mf5qw INFO: Shutting down 25 quiet workers
starkers@ubuntu:~/Desktop/app$ bundle exec sidekiq

         s
        ss
   sss  sss         ss
   s  sss s   ssss sss   ____  _     _      _    _
   s     sssss ssss     / ___|(_) __| | ___| | _(_) __ _
  s         sss         \___ \| |/ _` |/ _ \ |/ / |/ _` |
  s sssss  s             ___) | | (_| |  __/   <| | (_| |
  ss    s  s            |____/|_|\__,_|\___|_|\_\_|\__, |
  s     s s                                           |_|
        s s
       sss
       sss 

2014-04-25T19:17:01Z 8392 TID-61jek INFO: Running in ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
2014-04-25T19:17:01Z 8392 TID-61jek INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2014-04-25T19:17:01Z 8392 TID-61jek INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2014-04-25T19:17:01Z 8392 TID-rwouc INFO: Booting Sidekiq 3.0.0 with redis options {}
```

rails console:

```
reload!
u = User.last
u.send_sync_email #=> Rendered user_mailer/registration.text.erb (0.4ms)
u.send_async_email #=> "7dbefe20b8df15ea13f78a89"
```

Back over in sidekiq you should see the job with the same pid as returned by the send_async_email method:

```
2014-04-25T19:18:42Z 8392 TID-owsho Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-7dbefe20b8df15ea13f78a89 INFO: start
2014-04-25T19:18:46Z 8392 TID-owsho Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer JID-7dbefe20b8df15ea13f78a89 INFO: done: 3.758 sec
```